# How to implement the text cursor indicator in a Winapi program on Windows 10/11?

Tags: c++, winapi, accessibility

After turning on *Start/Settings/Ease of Access/Text Cursor Indicator* on Windows 10, Microsoft apps and edit controls paint a colored blob at each end of the text cursor.  I see that a program called EoAExperiences.exe is started when that setting is turned on, but its purpose is undocumented.  It does have an entry in the registry under this key:

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Accessibility\ATs\CursorIndicator

If EoAExperiences is doing the painting, does my C++ Winapi program somehow have to register with it, before it will highlight its text cursor?  If not, is there an API that I can call to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could refer to the Doc:[Ease of Access Assistive Technology Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/ease-of-access---assistive-technology-registration)

Whether you just want to change the the text cursor style? If so, I suggest you could try to use [SetSystemCursor function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setsystemcursor) or [SetCursor function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcursor)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but my program is a user rather than provider of assistive technologies.  SetSystemCursor and SetCursor are for the mouse cursor whereas my query is about the text cursor (caret).

Comment: Try to use [CreateCaret function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createcaret) to create a new shape for the system caret. For more details, you could refer to the Doc:[Using Carets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-carets)

Comment: Thanks, but CreateCaret cannot distinguish between the the caret and any blobs included in its bitmap, so the whole thing flashes.  Those blobs, when painted by Microsoft's assistive technology, are static.

Comment: You could try to use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-uiautomationoverview) and you could load UIAutomationCore.dll into it.